# SQL transaction/ErrorHandling/TryandCatch

Tags: sql-server-2012

Taking a SQL programming(2012 version) class and totally stuck, program wont work no matter how many times I try. The requirements (Questions) as well as what I have so far are below. Below the dashed line is another proc I wrote for error handling. Please help me finish this...please!

/*Create a Stored Procedure that accepts StockName, NewOpenPrice, NewClosePrice.

a. If the Stock Name does not EXIST a new record should be added into the dbo.Stocks table

b.  If the Stock Name does EXIST, the OpenPrice an ClosePrice will be updated with the newly inserted Prices.

c.  Insert and Update statements should be built using a transaction (Repeatable Read Isolation Level)

d.  A Try Catch Statement should be used for the Update and Insert statements.  If there is an error, the dbo.error_handler Stored Procedure should be called.
*/

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spc_Stocks

@Name  varchar(25), @NewOpenPrice money, @NewClosePrice money

as
BEGIN   
        CREATE TABLE dbo.Stocks (
        StockID int IDENTITY(1,1), 
        StockName varchar(50), 
        OpenPrice money, 
        ClosePrice money    )

        INSERT INTO dbo.Stocks
        SELECT 'Walmart',21.58,22.98 UNION
        SELECT 'Target',17.32,15.23 UNION
        SELECT 'Taco Bell',4.58,12.98 UNION
        SELECT 'Microsoft',7.15,8.15 UNION
        SELECT 'Apple',10.79,9.89

        Select StockName from stocks 
        where StockName = @Name 
------Name does NOT exist 
    if (@Name = NULL)
Begin
        Insert into dbo.Stocks (StockName)
        Values (@Name)
END
----If name DOES exist 
ELSE
    BEGIN
        Begin TRY
            Begin SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ 
            UPDATE dbo.Stocks SET OpenPrice =@NewOpenPrice, ClosePrice= @NewClosePrice where StockName = @Name
    Commit transaction
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
```

?!?!?!?!?!?

---

*This is my ErrorHandler stored proc query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.error_handler

as

BEGIN

DECLARE @errnum INT,
        @severity INT,
        @errstate INT,
        @proc NVARCHAR(126),
        @line INT,
        @message NVARCHAR(4000)
-- capture the error information that caused the CATCH block to be invoked
SELECT @errnum = ERROR_NUMBER(),
       @severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @errstate = ERROR_STATE(),
       @proc = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
       @line = ERROR_LINE(),
       @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Stocks]
      (@Name varchar(25), @OpenPrice MONEY, @ClosePrice MONEY)
AS
BEGIN

    -----Name does NOT exist
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT StockName FROM [dbo].[Stocks]
                    WHERE StockName = @Name) 

    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
            BEGIN TRAN
                INSERT INTO dbo.Stocks (StockName, OpenPrice, ClosePrice)
                VALUES (@Name ,@OpenPrice, @ClosePrice)
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH 
            EXEC dbo.error_handler
            ROLLBACK
        END CATCH

    END

    ----If name DOES exist 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
                BEGIN TRAN

                UPDATE dbo.Stocks SET OpenPrice =@OpenPrice, ClosePrice= @ClosePrice  
                where StockName = @Name
            Commit transaction
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRUANSACTION     
            EXEC dbo.error_handler

        END CATCH
    END
END
```